# How to iterate over a directory for files without including sub-directories in Bash

Tags: bash, files, directory, for, assignment

I need to parse through a directory that contains files and subdirectories however I am unable to use the find command. The for loop is supposed to go through each file and compare it to another directory but I cannot get it to pass over the subdirectories.

```
difference=0
for item in $1
do 
     if [[ -d $item ]]
     then 
             continue
     fi
     if [ ! -f "$2/$(basename $item)" ]
     then
          echo "$2/$(basename $item) is missing"
          difference=1 
     fi
     if [ diff $item "$2/$(basename $item)" ]
     then
          echo "$1/$(basename $item) is different"
          difference=1
     fi
done
```

Using the code above it does skip over the subdirectories but then also doesn't compare the files. I know that if I omit the first if statement with the continue and put:

```
for item in $(find $1 -type f)
```

It works however I am unable to use that function. Any help is greatly appreciated. Furthermore I also have the other directory comparing to this one since its the same code I didn't write it down.

Comment: See: [Globbing for only files in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20745656/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most natural way to address your problem.

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1  |  ...
```

> I am unable to use that function.

Please update your question to describe the constraint
in your setup which prevents running /usr/bin/find.

---

> but then also doesn't compare the files.

```
     if [[ -d $item ]]
     ...
     if [ ! -f "$2/$(basename $item)" ]
     ...
     if [ diff $item "$2/$(basename $item)" ]
```

The iteration is fine.

What you wanted on that last clause was

```
     if diff $item "$2/$(basename $item)"
```

That is, you want `if` to look at the `diff` exit status,
without `test` (`[`) getting involved.

Notice the difference between these two lines:

```
     if [ diff $item "$2/$(basename $item)" ]
     if   diff $item "$2/$(basename $item)"
```

---

Let's ask bash some example questions.

```
$ if   true;    then echo Yes; fi
Yes
$ if   false;   then echo Yes; fi
$ if [       ]; then echo Yes; fi
$ if [ true  ]; then echo Yes; fi
Yes
$ if [ false ]; then echo Yes; fi
Yes
$ if [ apple ]; then echo Yes; fi
Yes
```

Notice that the `[` bash builtin is approximately
equivalent to /usr/bin/[ , a synonym for /usr/bin/test.
Also, we are invoking /usr/bin/true and /usr/bin/false here.
They offer exit status of 1 and 0.
In four of the cases we're not forking off *any* child subprocess.

---

When authoring scripts,
you may find a linter like `shellcheck` useful.

Comment: The final if statement is supposed to compare the contents of the file with the file of the same name in the other directory but I'm not allowed to used cmp or else I could get it to work. As this is an assignment I'm unable to use find just to complicate things for me.

Comment: Thank you for updating the tags to mention "assignment".